# HashMap uses LinkedList internally

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public V get(Object key) {
if (key == null)
    return getForNullKey();
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
         e != null;
         e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
            return e.value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

What I knew is, if you want to get a object from `HashMap`, first of all it searches the hash bucket based on hashcode/hash value and then iterates through the `LinkedList` in that hashbucket(suppose the diff objects have same hash code, thus in the same hash bucket).

But after looking at the code above, I am not able to understand when it iterates through the LinekedList(and where is the LinkedList)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The bucket *is* the linked list, effectively. The `table` array is an array of `Entry` elements, and each `Entry` is a linked list, in that each entry knows about the next one in the list, until you reach the end when the `next` reference is null. The `for` loop you've shown iterates over the linked list.

It's not a `LinkedList` as in a `java.util.LinkedList` - it's a separate (simpler) implementation just for the map.

Answer (score 3):

It does use linked list, but not `java.util.LinkedList` class.

Basically `e.next` is something you're looking for.
Each entry has a reference to next entry in bucket - it's a linked list implementation.

Answer (score 2):

`e.next` is what you're looking for. Each entry has a reference to next entry in the bucket; it's a linked list implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The bucket is linkedlist.
table is an array which stores address of first entry(linkedlist) at an element of array.
Say at position0 in table array, two entry object needs to be stored then table[0] will store address of entry1(linkedlist) and entry1 will store address of entry2. For loops helps iterate through these entry objects.
`table[0] --> entry1 --> entry2 --> null // Hence output is entry2 of get().`

But the world has changed since Java 8 as tree is used to store entry object.