# Internal structure of Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I was going through the internal structure of `HashMap` and got stuck in the concept of how a bucket stores multiple objects.

As `HashMap` is an array of `Entry` objects, every index of array is a bucket. The `Entry` class is like

```
static class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {  
    K key;  
    V  value;  
    Entry<K,V> next_entry;  
    int hash;  
}
```

On Adding a new key-value pair

- If we are adding a value with a key which has already been saved in HashMap, then the value gets overwritten.
- Otherwise the element is added to the bucket. If the bucket already has at least one element, a new one is gets added and placed in the first position in the bucket. Its next field refers to the old element.

So how can a bucket store multiple object as per the 2nd point?

Comment: It *is not* array of these objects.

Comment: Where's the confusion? Which part of the 2nd point disallows you to store multiple objects in a single bucket?

Comment: there are no "buckets" in Java's `HashMap` implementation

Comment: @injecteer There are; `HashMap` is backed by an `Entry[]`, each element of which is a bucket.

Comment: You may read something on implementation of hash table, for example, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). It's almost the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

This is about HashMap in Oracle JDK 1.7.0.55.

Creating a new entry is done through:

```
void createEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
    table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<>(hash, key, value, e);
    size++;
}
```

which clearly shows that the already existing element is stored as next element of the new element. So the array contains the buckets. Buckets themselves are single linked lists made up of `Entry` elements.

And when a `get` operation is performed, then this single linked list is iterated as can be seen in the `for` loop of (comment by me)

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    if (size == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key);
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
         e != null;
         e = e.next) { // <- see here
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash &&
            ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

So the `Entry` elements of the single linked list all have keys with the same hash. But by the contract of `hashCode` objects not equal to each other may have the same hash codes. So using `key.equals(k)` in the above for loop will not be true for the first round in the loop in every case. So the loop may be traversed until the end of the linked list.

Comment: Oracle JDK 8 makes it more interesting - the entries may form either a linked list or a red-black tree...

Answer (score 0):

Java [`HashMap` uses a `linkedlist` for buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15768751/2970947) (but not a `java.util.LinkedList`). If a class hard codes the `hashCode()` method to a single value; instances of such a class loaded into a `HashMap` the structure will degenerate into a `linkedlist`. You override `equals()` to support replace in the "bucket".

Comment: I would say "linked lists" and not "`LinkedList`" to avoid confusion with `java.util.LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap maintains an array: Entry[]; each element of that array represents a "bucket".  The remainder of the entries in the bucket are accessed by traversing a linked list maintained in by Entry.next.